# Get binary image data from PIL.Image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've opened an image in PIL like so:

```
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open("image.jpg")
```

I need to access the raw contents of this file. How can I get the entire picture data, as if I would have done `open(...).read()`?

Comment: Since you accepted the ".tobytes" question, I am leaving this comment to make clear to future readers: you actually wanted "the raw pixel data", not the "raw contents of the file" - which is what I explained how to get.

Comment: Oh, really? Then I'll accept your answer, I want the original raw file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL uses a lazy opening mechanism, in which the file contents are only read when needed.
For doing that, it probably keeps the file reference in some internal (private) attribute.

Even if this attribute is accessible, it certainly is not exposed as part of the official PIL API - and it certainly is not meant to be used in this way.

Once the data is read, the file contents are decoded, and kept in memory as pixel values (which is usually what is desired when dealing with images). The library certainly does not keep the undecoded file data in a data structure in memory, as it would be meaningless.

If you want the raw file contents, you are likely processing the image with some other module, or storing it, or iterating over the data in a form that is agnostic to the actual image contents - can't you just open the file back with a regular "open"?

Comment: The correct answer indeed. At creation time, there's an `Image.fp` attribute available which points to the original file used to create the `Image` object. The attribute points to the file as long as its entire contents has not been read by the `Image` object. As soon as that happens `Image.fp` will point to `None` and no more reference to the original file is kept.

Answer (score 33):

you can see this answer [python Image PIL to binary Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921055/python-image-pil-to-binary-hex)

> The img object needs to be saved again; write it to another BytesIO
>   object:
>
> ```
> output = io.BytesIO()
> img.save(output, format='JPEG')
> ```
>
> then get the written data with the .getvalue() method:
>
> ```
> hex_data = output.getvalue()
> ```

Comment: I was using the Microsoft Cognition API and it requires a Binary Image Data.

I was first trying to send the data by using regular open function and also tried using encoding/decoding with base64, but it didn't work.

This did work, though, so if anyone uses it in the future, try getting the data in this form.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get the actual bytes of the image, just use [`i.tobytes()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes). This is with [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org), I'm not sure if it's in the original `PIL` module, but from the docs it should be.

Comment: This still doesn't give you the original file's bytes, only the raw (uncompressed) image bytes from memory. Easy enough to verify if you have a small image. 
`f = open('pic.jpg');`
`img = PIL.Image.open(f).tobytes();`
`f.seek(0);`
`img==f.read();`
should evaluate to `False`

Comment: From the official docs:
```Warning:

This method returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory data.```

Answer (score 6):

In PIL :

```
Image.open(path).convert('1')
```

As mentioned in [doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes)

**1** mode is for *(1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)*

Comment: All that does is create a new `PIL.Image.Image` object with the converted raw pixel data inside. This will not give you the original file's byte data, just a converted representation of that data.